# jacket expressions

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Does 'to open a jacket' mean to unbutton it?

Does 'to close a jacket' mean to button it up?

If a man's jacket is unbuttoned and he pulls the two sides further apart, exposing his chest, how would one describe what he does? Does he open his jacket? Does he open it wider?

If a man's jacket is unbuttoned and he pulls the two sides closer together, how would one describe what he does? Does he close his jacket?

Many thanks.